# Animate item in RecyclerView to another view in different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and a EditText in different layout. Now, I want to animate an item in RecyclerView to the EditText, in the end of the animation, the item will be invisible. Can someone tell me how to do this

I did the way in this link but it didn't work
[Animate a view from one Layout to other Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566306/animate-a-view-from-one-layout-to-other-layout)